# Spring parallel processing inside a transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have lots of micro services that perform database custom logic on pretty big data volumes. Every instance of these microservices use the following query: `select * from ENTITY_TABLE for update skip locked` to organize parallel work on this data and prevent data sets intersections.

The thing is that on each entity fecthed (batch size is around 100) I need to perform 3 more db requests and this takes pretty much time and not effective in general.

What I'd like to do is to organize parallel processing of each entity inside one big transaction. The main problem is that spring doesn't allow this. My code is something like this:

```
public class Manager {
    private final Fetcher fetcher;
    private final Processor processor;
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    public void doWork(int batchSize) {
        transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(status -> {
            List<MyEntity> entities = fetcher.fetch(batchSize);
            List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(MyEntity me : entities) {
                resultList.add(processor.process(entity));
            }
            CompletableFuture.allOf(resultList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
        });
    }
}

public class Fetcher {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    public List<MyEntity> fetch(int batchSize) {
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(batchSize);
        jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(batchSize);
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from ENTITY_TABLE for update skip locked", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(MyEntity.class);
    }
}

public class Processor() {
    @Async // <- this messes up transaction and makes it impossible to perform this work in parallel fashion inside transaction opened in the Manager class
    public void CompletableFuture<Boolean> process(MyEntity me) {
        boolean exists = repository.existsRelatedEntity(me.getId());
        if (!exists) {
            repository.createRelatedEntity(new RelatedEntity(/*..*/));
        } else {
            repository.updateRelatedEntity(me);
        }
        repository.markProcessed(me);
    }
}
```

And the question is: Do I have any options here to make this possible to parallel work on te process function? Do I have some possibility to point jdbcTemplate on the transaction it should use for its opertions?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Disclaimer: I know that I can mark all of the selected entities with help of additional update query and then process them one by one in separate transactions but I would like to see if I have any options here cause I simplified the code and in reality it is much more complex and would require a big rework in case of logic changes.

Answer (score 0):

If Fetcher and Processor are in the same service it should work in the same transaction after adding @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) annotation on public void doWork(int batchSize);
I tested this with spring repository instead of JdbcTemplate and it seems to be working.

If you have any errors, please add it to your post

Comment: What does specifying of isolation level is solving in my case? Are you suggesting to do select query without `for update skip locked` part and specify `isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED`? Sorry, didnt really get your idea.

Comment: Right, remove that line and remove explicit locks on update if you have. In this case db rows shouldn’t be blocked inside the transaction and because of isolation level read uncommitted you will be able to see already updated rows

Comment: It doesn't really fit my need cause some of the microservices can do select simultaneously and thus will work on the same entities which I try to avoid. More it doesn't address the original issue. So it seems like it is out of scope.

Comment: Oh, if you have a single db for all microservices it is definitely not possible.